# Is there a way to create a custom keyboard shortcut in OSX?

Tags: macos, keyboard, mojave

I'd like to press a custom set of keys (i.e. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>) to instead act like I am pressing a different set of keys (i.e. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>).

How can I accomplish this? In the keyboard shortcuts menu I'm only seeing ways to set keyboard keys to launch applications or change how the modifier keys work.

Comment: What does Control ] do for you now?

Comment: Well, in general, nothing. This is a silly request, but one of the web applications I use uses that key combination to do something. My keyboard doesn't have a Ctrl key on the right side and I can't reach Ctrl ] with one hand, so I wanted to remap it... :)

Comment: To change the shortcut assigned to an App's menu command, go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts and add it there, giving it the keyboard shortcut you want.

Comment: It's a website, not an app. Unfortunately there is no menu command for it. I simply want pressing 2 buttons to act as if I'm pressing 2 other buttons. Thank you though!

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: For my use case, it's an internal code review tool called Collaborator by Smart Bear. https://smartbear.com/product/collaborator/overview/. Ideally any solution for this question would work for all URLs though as I'm hoping to intercept keyboard commands and send a different one.

Comment: What browser are you using? Maybe an Automator Service (Quick Action in macOS Mojave) with some AppleScript _code_, e.g. `key code 30 using control down` or `keystroke "]" using control down` and assigning the Service a shortcut of: **^`**

Comment: Yeah, it's somewhat of a workaround, but user3439894 is right. The way to do this, though kludgey, is to create a service that just executes the `keystroke "]" using control ` applescript inside a tell block for System Events. Name the service something unique, and then create the keyboard shortcut to map the key combo you want to that name (it appears in a submenu under the apple menu). Then each time you type the shortcut, the other key combo will follow. Just make sure your key combo isn't already used by something else.

Comment: Interesting idea, thanks guys. I've never used Applescript before, I'll try to look into that. If someone wants to post a version as an answer I can mark it correct once I get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a viable solution, you'll have to give it a try and see:

- This answer uses **Safari** as the browser, change as needed.
- The *Service*<sup>1</sup>  was named **Collaborator Keystroke**, change as wanted.
- The keyboard shortcut assigned to the *Service* is **^`**, change as wanted.

For the **Automator** *Service*<sup>1</sup>:

Use the image below for the settings.

**ApplesScript** *code*:

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "]" using command down
```

[image]

For **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**:

[image]

**Note:** Sometimes with an **Automator** *Service*<sup>1</sup> and assigning a *keyboard shortcut*, you may first have to trigger it from the target App's **Services** menu one time. From then on the *keyboard shortcut* should work normally.

<sub><sup>1</sup> In **macOS Mojave** an **Automator** *Service* is called a *Quick Action*.</sub>

Comment: This works great but I'm nervous about one caveat. It wants me to allow Google Chrome to be able to control my computer when I attempt to run the script. I thought that this would have been at the system level before Chrome (or any other application, I tested it in TextEdit as well and it also required permission) gets the input. I feel it may not be secure to allow Chrome to have Accessibility permissions.

Comment: @ardavis, I've been using OS X/macOS for 13 years and have never had an issue giving any application accessibility access, including Google Chrome. I have never had a malicious incident in doing so and I have hundreds of script and services I created and used over the years!